# What is the expected value from these two different coin tossing games?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

Consider these two games:

Game $1$: Toss $4$ coins. If coins $1$ and $2$ are heads, you win $\$5$. If coins $3$ and $4$ are heads, you win an additional $\$5$.

Game $2$: Toss $3$ coins. If coins $1$ and $2$ are heads, you win $\$5$. If coins $2$ and $3$ are heads, you win an additional $\$5$.

My question is, which game will have the highest expected value for winnings? The case of game $1$ is simple. Receiving $\$5$ from tossing coins $1$ and $2$ and receiving $\$5$ from tossing coins $3$ and $4$ are independent events. Therefore, if the coins lands heads with probability $p$, the expected value of the winnings is$$
E(\text{Game} \; 1) = 5 p^2 + 5 p^2 = 10p^2.
$$
In game $2$, we still have the probability $p^2$ of winning the first $\$5$. However, the probability of receiving the additional $\$5$from coin $3$ is dependent upon having a heads in coin $2$. I figured so far that
$$E(\text{Game}\;2) = 5p^2 + x$$
I am not sure what $x$ is. Which result links the expected value of an event when conditional probabilities are involved?

EDIT: My solution approach is wrong, please see my comment below.

Comment: If in Game 1 you don't get two heads from tossing Coins 1 and 2, does it matter what you get from tossing Coins 3 and 4?  Your solution approach implies that it matters, but the problem statement seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi It matters. One can win $\$$5 if coins 3 and 4 are heads regardless of what coins 1 and 2 are. My solution approach is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In game $2$ you win $10$ if all the first three come up heads, which is probability $p^3$.  You win $5$ if the first three come up $HHT$ or $THH$, which is probability $2p^2(1-p)$.  The total expectation is $10p^3+10p^2(1-p)=10p^3+10p^2-10p^3=10p^2$.  The expectation is the same.

This is an example of the linearity of expectation.  The expectation from each pair is $5p^2$.  Each game has two pairs that matter.  The linearity of expectation does not require independence.